# Google sheets overwriting timestamp even with a lambda function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I'm using the following code as part of an attendance spreadsheet.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",(LAMBDA(x,x)(NOW())))
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",(LAMBDA(x,x)(NOW())))
=IF(ISBLANK(B4),"",(LAMBDA(x,x)(NOW())))
```

...etc.

The idea is that when a student scans in with an ID card, the scanner puts the student's ID in column B, and then column A gets autofilled with the time that the student logged in.

This works about 80% of the time, but sometimes large groups of times get overwritten simultaneously. For example today all of the times from 8:32 to 8:59 got overwritten.

3/6/2024 8:31:41
3/6/2024 8:31:48
3/6/2024 8:32:01
3/6/2024 8:32:05
3/6/2024 8:32:08
3/6/2024 8:32:12
3/6/2024 8:59:41
3/6/2024 8:59:41
3/6/2024 8:59:41
3/6/2024 8:59:41
3/6/2024 8:59:41
3/6/2024 8:59:41
3/6/2024 8:59:41
3/6/2024 8:59:41
3/6/2024 8:59:41

EDIT: I think this might be a SYNC issue. The computer that is gathering the data has different times than what is showing up on my computer.

Am I using lambda functions wrong, is there something else I should be doing, or are they just finicky? Thanks!

I tried moving the lambda from the beginning of the function to a spot in front of the now(), but that didn't solve the overwriting.

Comment: using LAMBDA to prevent volatile functions from recalculating is an undocumented _trick_ that many people use. For what we now this may not even be intended behavior and it could get fixed in the future. So if you want reliable timestamps you should not use this trick and use a script instead.